# problem with apt and dbkg

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

When I use the apt commands such as install, remove, autoremove and so on.. only output below is printed, which is related to the installation of the failed openvpn package that I previously intended to install with dpkg command. In fact, every time I use apt and dpkg cpmmands, system tries to  reinstall the package that failed to install it before. How can this problem be solved?

```
sudo apt install tree
[sudo] password for hosein: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 openvpn:i386 : Depends: liblzo2-2:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libpam0g:i386 (>= 0.99.7.1) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libpkcs11-helper1:i386 (>= 1.11) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libssl1.0.0:i386 (>= 1.0.2~beta3) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libsystemd0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
 tree : Conflicts: tree:i386 but 1.5.3-2 is to be installed
 tree:i386 : Conflicts: tree but 1.7.0-3 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was solved with the following command:
    rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/*

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install
```

This would try to fix dependency problems and reconfigure your packages.
Also there is command `dpkg --reconfigure` may help to solve .

Comment: I try and it did not work. as I said, the apt and dpkg commands do not work and generate the same output as above.

Comment: You going to get same error with all package which you want to install ? What's your hardware architect ?

Comment: yes. x86_64 GNU/Linux